# Run eclipse from command

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I just installed eclipse and I want to start it from the terminal, the problem is that when I write 'eclipse' from the terminal, it opens the installation of eclipse, instead I want it to open the executable directly, since I have already installed it.

how can I change the path of the terminal?

Comment: I followed this guide perfectly (it's in Italian): https://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/Programmazione/Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I solved simply edit the file / usr / local / bin / eclipse by inserting the right names of folders and files, as the guide used an old version of eclipse